# Core Audio ExtAudioFile using Client Channel Layout

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, extaudiofile

I’m trying to make use of `ExtAudioFile's` automatic channel layout mapping, but it doesn’t seem to work as I expected.

Here’s what I do:

- I open a 6-Channel WAVE file with `ExtAudioFileOpenURL()`
- set the client data format property (`kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat`) to 6-Channel PCM Audio Unit Canonical
- just out of curiosity read the file’s channel layout property (`kExtAudioFileProperty_FileChannelLayout`)
  the resulting `AudioChannelLayout` struct has a `kAudioChannelLayoutTag_MPEG_5_1_A` which is correct (the file is L-R-C-LFE-LS-RS)
- set the client channel layout property (`kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientChannelLayout`)
  now, I use the slightly different `kAudioChannelLayoutTag_MPEG_5_1_C`, which is L-C-R-LS-RS-LFE, which is what I want to use in my audio graph
- then, the file is read with `ExtAudioFileRead()` into an `AudioBufferList`
- the buffer list is played back by the audio graph: scheduled sound player -> matrix mixer (to down-convert the 5.1 signal to stereo) -> default out

Everything works fine, except the channel mapping doesn’t. The matrix mixer still receives a L-R-C-LFE-LS-RS stream.

I checked the docs for `kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientChannelLayout`:

> This property’s value specifies the channel layout of the buffers in
>   an `AudioBufferList` list that you pass to the `ExtAudioFileRead` and
>   `ExtAudioFileWrite` functions. This layout may be different from the
>   file’s channel layout, in which case the extended audio file object’s
>   underlying audio converter performs remapping. This property must be
>   set after setting `thekExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat` property,
>   and the number of channels in the two layouts must match.

I feel like I did it right, but I must be missing something… Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Comment: The `ExtAudioFile` portions seems correct.  Do you set any channel layouts on your `AUGraph`?

Comment: No, only on the ExtAudioFile. Where in the graph do you suggest it to be set?

Comment: I played around with setting channel layouts on my audio units, but no success. I always get kAudioUnitErr_InvalidProperty...